# How enable debug logging in LoopBackJs framework on WebStorm IDE?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, loopbackjs

I use WebStorm IDE for a LoopBack project and I want to set the log level of some part of framework to debug level. I found this tutorial for changing the log level in LoopBack framework:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html

I don't know how should I set it in the WebStorm. My OS is Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables inside Webstorm in the [Run/Debug configuration menu](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html).

You need the Node JS plugin enabled.

Then, just add a `DEBUG` variable and for the value set the appropriate [debug string](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html), or use a wildcard `*` to print all debug logs.